# jQuery click on appended list element

Tags: jquery, delegates, append

I know this question is already posted, but the solutions proposed are not working in my case:

I append an element like this:

```
var premier = '<div class="container col-md-8">' +
              '<div class="row">' +
              '<ul class="list">' +
              '<li class="title"><a id="'+ide+'" href="">'+nom+'</a></li>' +
              '<li class="artist">'+art+'</li>' +
              '<li class="stars"><img src='+stars+'></li>' +
              '<li class="gender">'+gen+'</li>' +
              '</ul>' +
              '</div>' +
              '<hr>' +
              '</div>';
```

With this command:

```
$('.main').append(premier);
```

Then I want to acces to the element a by an onclick function:

```
$('#'+ide+'').on('click',function(){
  console.log("do it");
});
```

But it doesn't work. I have probe also with delegate function but maybe I am using it wrong.

Comment: Could you post your html as well

Comment: Try `$('.main').on('click', '#' + ide, function(){ console.log("do it"); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) click for dynamically added element.

```
$( document).on( "click", "#"+ide, function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqpkyjvu/)

Comment: @Laura : can you create a fiddle. as it working in fiddle. See here https://jsfiddle.net/bqpkyjvu/

Comment: Its working now!!! I think the problem was this line: '<li class="title"><a id="' + ide + '" href="">' + nom + '</a></li>' +    You wrote it in the right way and it works perfectly!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variables if you already declared your variables cant get your your values on your variables

```js
var ide="hello";
var nom="hello2";
var art = 'hello3';
var stars = 'hello3';
var gen = 'hello3';
var premier = '<div class="container col-md-8">' +
  '<div class="row">' +
  '<ul class="list">' +
  '<li class="title"><a id="' + ide + '" href="">' + nom + '</a></li>' +
  '<li class="artist">' + art + '</li>' +
  '<li class="stars"><img src=' + stars + '></li>' +
  '<li class="gender">' + gen + '</li>' +
  '</ul>' +
  '</div>' +
  '<hr>' +
  '</div>';
  
$('.main').append(premier);

$('#' + ide + '').on('click', function() {
      alert("do it");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

</div>
```

Comment: @Shiladitya go try it

Comment: I'm saying the same code is posted by OP. How it is different?

Comment: This is exactly what I have, I have already declared the variables as you did, but it doesnt work in my case

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation should be done on dynamic elements

```
$('.main').on('click', '#' + ide, function(){ 
  console.log("do it"); 
});
```

Reference Document: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Hope this will help you.